# Derived type in COMMON has neither the SEQUENCE nor the BIND(C) attribute

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran, derived-types

I am new to Eclipse. I have an issue with my old Fortran code I developed. I migrated my source files to Eclipse and I am experiencing issue with derived type variables I didn't have before.

```
PROGRAM main
IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (a-h,o-z)
INCLUDE 'types.h90'
INCLUDE 'Lsode.h90'
INCLUDE 'common.h90'

...


END PROGRAM main
```

My common.h90 file contains:

```
COMMON /entier/ ent
```

And I am getting an error Derived type variable 'ent' in COMMON at (1) has neither the SEQUENCE nor the BIND(C) attribute. Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks in advance

NB. My derived type variables are correctly declared in types.h90 ...

```
TYPE entier
 INTEGER :: nc
 INTEGER :: nr
 INTEGER :: nz
END TYPE entier
```

Comment: Please use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score 1):

Common blocks are old and do not really work well with modern features.

Derived types should normally be always defined only once - typically in a module.

Common blocks, on the other hand, are used to define everything in many places separately. There are restrictions for what can be in common blocks. Notably, for derived types Fortran has:

> If a common-block-object is of a derived type, the type shall have the
> BIND attribute or the SEQUENCE attribute and it shall have no default
> initialization.

This there to make sure that such a derived type is always the same and that there is no freedom for the compiler for the padding between different components.

Your derived type must have the `sequence` attribute, or the `bind(C)` attribute to use it in a common block.

```
TYPE entier
 sequence
 INTEGER :: nc
 INTEGER :: nr
 INTEGER :: nz
END TYPE entier
```

or

```
TYPE, bind(C) :: entier
 INTEGER :: nc
 INTEGER :: nr
 INTEGER :: nz
END TYPE entier
```

---

**My actual advice is**: get rid of the common blocks, use modules instead. And, for sure, get rid of the implicit typing, use `implicit none` everywhere.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of what should I do exactly since I don't understand?